# How can we add multiple foreign keys from one model to another on ASP.NET Core & EF Core & C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So let's say I have an `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` model class that has the identity relations and it has a String ID by default and roles assigned when the user signs up.

`ApplicationUsers` will have different roles for example Student and Library.

The Library will have a list of books while the Student will have list of orders.

Now I want to create a List of another model which will have the name `Orders`, but the `Orders` model class will have two UserIds as foreign keys from `ApplicationUser`.

```
ApplicationUser: IdentityUser 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Libraries> Libraries { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Since the `ApplicationUser` is connected with `ASPNetRoles`, what I want to achieve on `Orders` model class is that I want to have different `StudentId` and `LibraryId` from the same table which is `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class Orders 
{ 
    [Key]
    public id OrderId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Student {get; set;}
 
    [ForeignKey("LibraryId")]
    public string LibraryId {get; set;} 
    public ApplicationUser Library {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? What are the best solutions for this case? I did try `ICollection` and list but still same. Any suggestion about this would be great.

When I run `Add-Migrations`, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ApplicationUser.OrdersLists' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Thank you.

Comment: The `[ForeignKey]` attribute on a FK field should point at the navigation property. I.e. `[ForeignKey("Student")]` not "StudentId".. (Same for "Library") If the attribute is on the navigation property, then it should reference the FK field. It's a bit weird, but think of it as either "I am the foreign key of..." or "this is my foreign key..." from the point of view of which side you put the attribute on.

Comment: @StevePy thanks for answering, I did that and i still get the same error. The problem is that I want to add TWO FKs from ONE TABLE which is the Users Table.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that, which would require the [ForeignKey] attribute to be straightened out.. You will also need to link the relationship to the other side so that EF knows which "many" maps to which "one" in the relationship. The mapping of a Order.Library to an ApplicationUser is a bit confusing given it looks like you have a Library class as well where ApplicationUser has a Libraries collection. I have added more detail in an answer below.

Comment: `ApplicationUser: IdentityRole` You mean `IdentityUser`? You can probably find your answer on the EF Core Relationships documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration specifically "Manual configuration" / "Data annotations"

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes you are right, I have mistaken it while i was writing, i did mean  IdentityUser, I will edit this now. I will also check the link.

Comment: @StevePy I will try your suggestion and the bottom answer ASAP tonight.
Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, something in you model doesn't look quite right...

In your User class you have a collection of Orders and an collection of a class called Library. Yet within your Order class you have a property called Library, but point that at an ApplicationUser class?

EF does support having multiple references to the same class, though you need to explicitly tell it what the FK names would be. EF's default convention is to base FK names on the *type* of the navigation property, not the name of the navigation property.

Take the following:

```
public class Order
{
    ....

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int LastModifiedById { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Here by default EF would want to use "ApplicationUser_Id" or "ApplicationUserId" as a FK name for both of the two navigation properties, settling on something like "ApplicationUser_Id" and "ApplicationUser_Id1" if left to its own devices with the schema.  In this situation we would need to configure it to use our desired FK properties:

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("LastModifiedBy")]
public int LastModifiedById { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

or the FK attribute can be put on the navigation property:

```
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

public int LastModifiedById { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("LastModifiedById")]
public virtual ApplicationUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

The `ForeignKey` Attribute is a bit weird, as it represents either "I am the FK of ..." if on the FK property, or it represents "My FK is ...." if on the navigation property.

With EF Core the FK property can be left off and treated by EF as a shadow property which is recommended to avoid having two sources of truth in the entity.

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("LastModifiedById")]
public virtual ApplicationUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

In situations where you want bi-directional references in the other side of the relationship, you may need to map those out. For instance if I want a "CreatedOrders" in my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Order> CreatedOrders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}
```

Now it's generally a good idea to tell EF what to relate this back to since Order has two references to the application user. Again, this can be done on either side of the relationship. So in the case of back in our Order class:

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedById"), InverseProperty("CreatedOrders")]
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

This tells EF that CreatedBy on this record is the link to use when accessing the orders for CreatedOrders.

Back to your example it is a bit confusing why ApplicationUser would contain a collection of Libraries while an Order expects a "library" to be a User.

Comment: *“Here by default EF would want to use "ApplicationUser_Id" or "ApplicationUserId" as a FK name for both of the two navigation properties…“* I always thought EF default logic here is `<navigation property name>Id` which does make more sense when I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#fully-defined-relationships

Comment: @Steve Py this was exactly what I was looking for, now I am able to connect a Model with two ApplicationUsers as ForeignKeys. 
Do not mind my example that much, it was just to demonstrate what I want to achieve with my models. Thank you for your reply, it did the work.

Quick question: Will this work with more than two FKs? I am going to try it soon.

Have a wonderful day.

Comment: If you mean for 3 or more references to the same table, like CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, ViewedBy all referencing User with potentially User having bi-directional collections of orders for all 3, You can have as many as you need provided you let EF know which FK maps to what reference, and which collection on the other side. (if any)  Usually these issues boil down to that EF can work out several scenarios automatically by convention, but when you need to go beyond that, you need to add configuration. I tend to just apply configuration to everything and ignore convention. Fewer surprises.